# AnimatedSwitcher not animating

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Can someone please help understand why this simple animated swticher doesnt work?

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool _showFrontSide = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final face = _showFrontSide ?
      Container(key: const ValueKey(true), child: Text("Front")) :
      Container(key: const ValueKey(false), child: Text("Back"));

    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => {
          setState(() {
            _showFrontSide = !_showFrontSide;
          })
        },
        child: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(microseconds: 1500),
          transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
            return ScaleTransition(scale: animation, child: child);
          },
          child: face,
        ));
  }
}
```

Full example can be seen here:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=d1e94dc9e6b1fe901f6bfe6a1149be64

Almost all discussions point to setting a unique key on the children for animateswitcher to detect a change, and trigger animating. I dont understand why it doesnt work in this case.

Comment: This may help you https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-animatedswitcher-widget-examples

Comment: It works, but the `Duration` is too short to be visible (`microseconds` are not visible to our eyes). Try to set `milliseconds` instead of `microseconds` and the animation will become visible.

Comment: Wow, thanks @AnteBule. If you post this as comment I'll close by accepting it as answer

Comment: Ok, I've posted an answer instead of a comment since you requested it. Happy coding 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but the `Duration` is too short to be visible (`microseconds` are not visible to our eyes). Try to set `milliseconds` instead of microseconds and the animation will become visible.

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  ...
),
```